# Send keystrokes to guest os with vmrun

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools, vmrun

I can't find documentation or examples of how use `typeKeystrokesInGuest` command of `vmrun` tool.

I tried send key code, like `30` and I try send `Some text`, but always got
`Insufficient permissions in the host operating system`. I think, I must give right permission, but I don't know where, and I don't know is I use described command in properly way.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. Do you have a solution now?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, vmrun uses the VIX API which is slated to be deprecated. A new option is to use the PutUsbScanCodes method that is available with the vSphere 6.5 API and does not have a dependency of VMware Tools running on the guest OS.

More information is available at the following: https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2017/09/automating-vm-keystrokes-using-the-vsphere-api-powercli.html

Answer (score 0):

Govc it's supposed to do this job as well I have found a bug which I'm hoping they'll fix soon